# Xcode 9 auto layout X central if no sibling

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In Xcode, when using auto layout, I wanted to position a button so that if this button doesn't have sibling button then it should align X center, otherwise both can sit side by side.

I have tried with yellow.leadingSpace to superview >= 20, yellow.alignX to superview, but it is not working, yellow button always stays on the left.

[image]

Comment: You can add this in stack view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as Uma already suggested you can use a [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) for this. Simply add both buttons to the `UIStackView` and set the spacing. You also could do it without a `UIStackView` with a combination of constraints:

1. Add a horizontal center constraint to the first button.
2. Change the priority of this constraint to `750`.
3. Add a spacing constraint between the buttons.
4. When second button gets hidden you need to disable the spacing constraint by `buttonPaddingConstraint.isActive = false`.
5. If you show the second button again you need to re-add the spacing constraint by: `leftButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true`

If you want to animate hiding one of the buttons the outcome depends method to use.
If you are going to use a `UIStackView` have a look at "First Button" and "Second Button" in the following image.
If you are going without a `UIStackView` have a look at "Third Button" and "Fourth Button".
[image: autolayout]

I uploaded the xcode project containing both options [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N16hceF7a7MKr59T6mb9BAYBlFirGe3I).